# jQM buttons with custom background colors have pixelated corners

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

So I'd like to use some custom colors for my jQuery Mobile buttons, but when I do so  it seems to do something funky to the (rounded) corners. The more "border-radius" I use, the more pixelated the corners get. Here's an example...

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pxws02au/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   #buttons .ui-btn {
      background: rgb(0,0,255);
      border-radius: 1em;
   }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="buttons">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">1</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">2</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the borders altogether (border: none), that solves the pixelation issue. But I would prefer a solution that allows me to keep (and style) the borders.

I tested the above link with my laptop (Chrome & FF), my Android phone, and my Android tablet... and the button corners are pixelated across all devices.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the background to go outside of the border using `background-clip: padding-box`

```css
#buttons .ui-btn {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 255) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  background-clip: padding-box; /* Add */
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

[image: Transparent border]

Comment: Thanks... but as mentioned above, I want to *keep* the border. For example... what if I want a blue button background, and a green button border. How would I do that without getting the pixelated corners?

Comment: Thanks... that's a creative answer. That takes care of the pixelation outside of the borders, but the border itself still looks fairly pixelated at the corners... especially when it's on top of a bright page background. Perhaps a bit of box shadow would help the corners to blend better. I'll do some more experimenting and reply back if I can get it to blend any better. I appreciate your reply :)